# Why does the Huntsman seem to be more accurate/powerful than a sniper rifle?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-sniper

I've noticed that I do far more damage with the Huntsman than I do with the standard sniper rifle, and,  not only do my arrows *hit* enemies more often than sniper bullets, but they also *head-shot* far more often as well.

However, according to the TF2 [wiki](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Weapons#Sniper), both the sniper rifle and the Huntsman have the same accuracy, but the Huntsman is actually weaker (having a damage output of 44-137, as opposed to the stock sniper's 43-172). Why is it, then, that the Huntsman hits enemies (and head-shots them) more often than the stock rifle, and why does it seem to be more accurate than the stock?

Comment: ...you're trying to compare the accuracy of a hit-scan weapon and a projectile weapon?

Comment: Huntsman has a larger hitbox, meaning you get headshots with a Huntsman arrow that would register as misses with a rife bullet. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48331/whats-the-huntsmans-headshot-criteria/48382#48382